# How to mount ZFS drive on Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, zfs

A friend of mine asked me to back up his drive, but its file system is ZFS. I would like to know how can I mount that on Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a zfs package available at launchpad, at https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Comment: Charles thanks, is there any particular package that I need to install from that repository? I see there's a couple dosen packages in that repo.

Comment: It should be ubuntu-zfs